# Adjust SKU on drupal nodes

Tags: php, drupal, view, ubercart

I'm trying to change 600 products so that the node SKU is set to the value of the node's title. I want to use VBO to accomplish this, with the "execute arbitrary PHP script" option. Here is the code I am using:

```
$new_node = node_load($object->nid);
$new_node->model = $object->title;
node_save($new_node);
```

However, this does not work. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just set the sku with tokens.

For Drupal commerce you use: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_autosku

For ubercart: http://drupal.org/project/uc_product_power_tools

Once you set up the token rule then all you need to do is load and save all the nodes.

Not real sure what your code above is doing. I would use the devel execute php page and just run a one time script. Something like:

```
$sql = 'select nid from {node}'
$results = db_query($sql);
while ($nid = db_result($result)) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  node_save($node);
}
```

Been a while since I've used drupal 6 database api so I probably botched the functions above but it should give you the right idea.